# How to use if else statement in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, continuous-integration

How can I check `if else` condition in mysql before assigning `where` condition? I need a query for following logic.I used php code just to show what i want to do. I need a mysql query replacing the if else php code. I was wondering if we can do if type equals to 1 then do this else do this and type is a column of the table.

```
$this->db->select('startdate, enddate, type');
$this->db->from('db_date')
$this->db->where('id !=', $id);

if(`type`=1){
  $this->db->where("`early` <= ABS(DATEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(`startdate`, '%m-%d-%Y'),        CURDATE())/30)");
} else if(`type`=2){
  $this->db->where("`last` >= ABS(DATEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(`startdate`, '%m-%d-%Y'), CURDATE())/30)");
}else do nothing
```

Comment: What is stopping you to build conditions in php ?

Comment: why you use type =1 in both conditions

Comment: WHERE (type = 1 AND early > $days) OR (type = 2 AND last > $days) ?  Though the question doesn't make sense.  What does your table look like?  What do you actually want to get out of it.

Comment: Twice type equals one and trying it with mysql I dont even think this is possible use php statements instead

Answer (score 1):

You use CASE WHEN

```
 SELECT CASE 1 WHEN 1 THEN 'one'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'two' ELSE 'more' END;
    'one'

SELECT CASE WHEN 1>0 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END;
     'true'

SELECT CASE BINARY 'B'
     WHEN 'a' THEN 1 WHEN 'b' THEN 2 END;
    NULL
```

You can also use inline (and nested) IFs

```
SELECT IF(score > 100, 100, IF(score < 0, 0, score)) FROM exam_results
```

A sample of IF+ WHERE clause:

```
SELECT ...
 WHERE ...
 AND IF(myfield = 'somevalue', 1, 0) = 1
```

You can combine those instructions with something like [EXECUTE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) or this eval function:
http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/mysql-eval

And the result would similar to:

```
  SELECT CASE 1 WHEN 1 THEN <call eval making a select with one type of where>
        WHEN 2 THEN <call eval making a select with another type of where> END;
```

I would say that this is not something very "conventional".

There is probalby a better and more maintanable way to do what you need.